# How to get the path for the SetBinding method on an IContentItemProxy in LightSwitch?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to create a binding to change the background color of a label based on a property of the selected item.  I'm using the form:

```
this.FindControl("ItemDisplayTitle")
        .SetBinding(TextBox.BackgrounProperty, **PATH**, 
             new MyIconverter(), BindingMode.OneWay);
```

If I use "Value" as the path, it uses the value of ItemDisplayTitle to set the color using MyIconverter()

But I really want to use another property "Health" which is on the screen but is a Local Property for this window.

Research has show me that I should [use the form "Details.Entity.AnotherProperty "](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e901f2c7-a416-46ff-8144-c7b6ab3af31d/modifying-background-color-of-datagrid-based-on-data-in-grid) 
*June 06, 2012 10:16 AM - Otis Ranger*

But when I try to use "DataSourceName.MyEntityName.MyProperty" it does not seem to work.
I've also tried "Details.MyEntityName.MyProperty"
and in desperation "Details.Entity.MyProperty"

I pretty sure I'm just having a mental hiccup, but what should
**Details**, **Entity** and **AnotherProperty** be?  and am I missing a obvious reference page to what exactly the path should be?

Comment: Are you adding this to the screen code? and your property is local to that screen?

Comment: I am adding this to the screen code.  The property is in the datasource, but also is displayed on that screen.

Comment: I've done something similar, but bound my controls in xaml. If this code is added to the screen then your entities should show up in the screens data context. `this.customers.FirstName` or `this.CreatedScreenProperty` in xaml the path for these properties were preceded by "Screen" like `{Binding Path="Screen.MyProperty Mode="TwoWay}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you should add a handler to **every row** on data grid. They are 3 easy steps.

Fist the result, notice than you can bind all row or a single control in row:

[image]

- **Step 1**. Declare converter. I assume that your converter runs fine.

This is my converter:

```
Public Class BooleanDateConverter

    Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object,
                            ByVal targetType As System.Type,
                            ByVal parameter As Object,
                            ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) _
             As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert


        If DirectCast(value, Boolean) Then
            Return New System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(
               System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(170, 102, 255, 245))
        Else
            Return New System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(
               System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(170, 255, 0, 0))
        End If

    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object,
                        ByVal targetType As System.Type,
                        ByVal parameter As Object,
                        ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) _
    As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack

        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

- **Step 2 and 3**. Bind datagrid and datagrid rows:

Binding datagrid on InitializeDataWorkspace:

```
    Private Sub Conversio_CategoriaPDI_a_ElementDeCosts_InitializeDataWorkspace(
         saveChangesTo As System.Collections.Generic.List(
               Of Microsoft.LightSwitch.IDataService))

        AddHandler Me.FindControl(
                      "TConversio_CategoriaPDI_a_ElementDeCosts"
                   ).ControlAvailable, AddressOf bindejarDataGrid

    End Sub
```

This is the handler for datagrid. Binding to everyrow inside function:

```
    Private Sub bindejarDataGrid(
           sender As Object, 
           e As Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.ControlAvailableEventArgs)

        AddHandler DirectCast(e.Control, Windows.Controls.DataGrid
                   ).LoadingRow, AddressOf bindejar
    End Sub
```

Binding some control row for every row:

```
    Private Sub bindejar(sender As Object, 
                         e As Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs)
        Dim b As Windows.Data.Binding = New Windows.Data.Binding("parametritzat")
        b.Mode = Windows.Data.BindingMode.OneTime
        b.Converter = New BooleanDateConverter
        b.ValidatesOnExceptions = True
        e.Row.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Label.BackgroundProperty, b)

    End Sub
```

Thanks to:

- [Otis Ranger](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e901f2c7-a416-46ff-8144-c7b6ab3af31d/modifying-background-color-of-datagrid-based-on-data-in-grid)
- [pragmaswitch.com](http://blog.pragmaswitch.com/?p=895)

Comment: Thank you.  I think I've been struggling with the general concept for the last few days. I'm going to take another attempt at things today.